# Share common code between Xamarin.Forms and Qt project

Tags: c#, c++, qt, xamarin.forms, shared-libraries

I would like to **share common code** between a **Xamarin.Forms project (C#)** and a **Qt project (C++)**.

Have you got a solution?

I try with a Visual C# Class Library which builds a DLL file. I succeeded to reference and use it in the Xamarin.Forms project, but I failed to use it in Qt. I supposed this is because the DLL is compiled from C# code.

Thanks.

Comment: C++ can only access managed code via the managed extensions for C++, but managed code can PInvoke C++ methods. So if you want to share code between them, the shared code would probably be better off in a C++ dll.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put the shared code in your C# dll, you should be able to use it from Xamarin (depending on what libraries it uses) and also [call it from your C++ code](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736).